# Push content javascript content

Tags: javascript

How can i push my content the same as another content? OK i know the question seems kind of vague but what I want to do is push my content like the way another script is pushing its content. What is doing when clicking the button it will push the content from the side causing the div to contract. I am not too far so maybe somebody can help. This is the script that works:

```
$(function(){
    var $trigger = $(".icon-menu-2");
    var $menu = $(".c_left");

$trigger.toggle(function show() {
    $menu.animate({ width: 185, marginLeft: 0, display: 'toggle'}, 'slow');
    $(".c_right").animate({ marginLeft:185, display:'toggle'}, 'slow');
}, function hide() {
    $menu.animate({ marginLeft: -185, display: 'toggle'}, 'slow');
    $(".c_right").animate({ marginLeft:0, display:'toggle'}, 'slow');
    });
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ndvbn/2/

Here is the script that needs just a small touch up so that it will push the content just like the script above does when clicking on test. Here is the script:

```
var timer;

$("#slideout").animate({right:'0px', queue: false, duration: "slow"}, function () {
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
        $("#slideout").animate({right:'-280px'}, {queue: false, duration: "slow"})
    }, 500);
});
$("#clickme2").click(function () {
    if ($("#slideout").css("right") == "-280px"){
        $("#slideout").animate({right:'0px'}, {queue: false, duration: 500}, function () {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        });
    } else {
        $("#slideout").animate({right:'-280px'}, {queue: false, duration: 500}, function () {
        clearTimeout(timer);
    });}
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5UpHk/4/

Can anybody post the code so that my second script will push the content to the left?

Answer (score 0):

This script below will push the content to the left. I made a couple of changes to the CSS as well. Check out the demo and code here: http://jsfiddle.net/BdKhW/1/

```
var timer;

$("#slideout").animate({width:'275px'}, {queue: false, duration: "slow"}, function () {
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
        $("#slideout").animate({width:0}, {queue: false, duration: "slow"})
        $(".c_left").animate({marginRight:0}, {queue: false, duration: "slow"})
    }, 2000);
});
$(".c_left").animate({marginRight:'275px'}, {queue: false, duration: "slow"})

$("#clickme2").click(function () {
    $("#slideout").animate({width:0}, {queue: false, duration: "slow"})
    $(".c_left").animate({marginRight:0}, {queue: false, duration: "slow"})
});
```